# Google Calendar have calendar owner receive email notification of new event

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, google-api-nodejs-client

I need to write a nodejs app that will be responsible for adding events to a gsuite users google calendar with the following requirements:

- A new event should be added to the user's google calendar
- The user should have ownership of the event and be able to reschedule/delete it
- The user should receive an email invitation/notification to the calendar event in their inbox immediately after creation

My initial thoughts were to use the google calendar API [events.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) to add an event to the users calendar, and set the [sendUpdates](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#sendUpdates) param to `all`, expecting it to send an email notification to the user notifying them that an event was added to their calendar.

However when testing this using my gmail in the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#try-it), the event is created successfully but no email is sent. I set `calendarId` to `primary`, `sendUpdates` to `all`, put in a `start` and `end` time in the future, added my gmail as an `attendee`, clicked Execute, signed in to the API Explorer, and the request succeeds, event is created in my calendar, but no email.

If I add another email that is different from the account owner as an `attendee`, an email IS sent to them but not the calendar owner (me). I need an email sent to calendar owner.

In production I plan to use a service account with delegated authority in the gsuite to impersonated users, and I tested this concept with the service account and got the same result as described above.

Is this possible using the calendar API?

Comment: Are you authenticating with OAuth2? Have you inlcude yourself (the creator of the event) as an attendee? Maybe the right call would be using a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) to invite all the attendees including yourself? What do you mean that the service account has the same results?

Comment: @Raserhin Yes I have authenticated with OAuth2 using the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#try-it) and included myself as an attendee. I have also tried using a service account. I can add other attendees but the calendar owner never gets the email. I need to notify the calendar owner an event was just created in their calendar.

Comment: Same problem. No answers for two years. Up

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick. Lets imagine that the event creator account is `testspongebob@gmail.com`. If you put it into the at `attendees` list as it is , e. g.

```
  "attendees": [
    {
      "email": "testspongebob@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
```

it wont work. I solved it using the gmail trick: modify the event creator account following the example below:

```
  "attendees": [
    {
      "email": "testspongebob+01@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
```

Gmail recognizes that `testspongebob+01@gmail.com` == `testspongebob@gmail.com`. But for Google Calendar API the emails are distinct. This way the event creator will receive the standard notification email. Also, don't forget to put `sendUpdates=all`